# changing timezone in Laravel 8 not working, even after running commands

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, utc

I have changed the timezone from `UTC` to `my/timezone` inside `config/app.php`. Still I'm getting no effect.
I tried these below commands also-

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan config:cache

php artisan optimize:clear
```

I found same issue on internet but the solutions doesn't work for me. **What I'm missing ?**

Comment: set your timezone in php.ini

Comment: i tried. but no result @MartinAmu